# What is the difference between 도수 versus 빈도?

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference between `도수`and `빈도`? In an example like this,

> 제가 단어의 나타나는 도수로 공부하고 있었어요.

, I learned that `빈도` was more appropriate but still don't have a clear understanding of the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically the same meaning. They're used without distinction most of the time. For example, the mathematical term "relative frequency" is both referred to as 상대 빈도 and 상대 도수. I'd say 빈도 is more common than 도수.

But, if you really think about it, the nuance is slightly different. In my opinion: 도수(度數) is a number(數), a number of times something happening. While 빈도(頻度) does not imply it's the exact count of something happening. The scales and manner of measuring it can differ by context. Compare 온도(溫度) and 난도(難度), they both have no "definite" scales. If you say something is "frequent", it's a 빈도, but not 도수. For example, 잦은 빈도 is OK, but 잦은 도수 sounds off.